# Get cpanel logs daabase

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, cpanel

I am using Cpanel and it has an awesome statistics manager.

Currently I have a web system which needs to count the statistics.

I have two options:

1. Manually code each entry
2. Use the Cpanel statistics

Is there any database associated with that?
I am using CodeIgniter framework.

Or, alternatively, is there any other option available?

Comment: well,i think that the question is not yet answerd.

Answer (score 0):

cpanel stores the logs in /tmp directory, check if you have access to that, if you have, make a php script to crawl through that.

Comment: but i think that there is some API,can i use that ?